# Having trouble grouping with django query

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have this query, but it returns individual results for each Fruit.  How do I get grouped results?

```
        Fruit.objects.\
                annotate(quantity=Count('fruit_box')).\
                annotate(remaining=Count('pk', filter=~Q(fruit_status='eaten'))).\
                annotate(eaten=Subquery(ShipmentContent.objects.filter(
                                            object_id=OuterRef('pk'),\
                                            fruits__fruit_box=OuterRef('fruit_box'),\
                                            shipment=self.request.query_params.get('shipment_id'),\
                                            fruits__fruit_status='eaten',\
                                            content_type=fruit_content_type).\
                                            values('object_id').\
                                            annotate(count=Count('object_id')).\
                                            values('count')\
                                        )\
                        ).\
                annotate(location=F('fruit_box__location__description')).\
                values('fruit_box__label', 'fruit_box', 'harvest_date', 'seeded').\
                order_by('fruit_box__label')
```

Comment: I am not sure of what you exactly want, but for grouping, you'll need to use `aggregate` instead of `annotate`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is enough info to fully answer your question. What do you want to group by? It may be that all you need to do is put the `.values(...)` call before the `.annotate(...)` calls.